# SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9) Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-4

I'm getting this error when trying to connect to an SQL Server DB from Laravel 4.2.
Here's my DB config:

```
'connections' => array(
  'sqlsrv' => array(
     'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
     'host'     => 'example.noip.me',
     'database' => 'db',
     'username' => 'sa',
     'password' => 'pass',
     'prefix'   => '',
   ), 
),
//...
```

It works perfectly in my home computer, but not in production. This project is in a hosting service, so I can't change much of the config (can still use `ini_set` though).
I tried adding the port to the server address but it didn't work.
Edit: I forgot to mention that the hosting and the database server are on different computers, so it could be a security configuration problem.

Comment: Are you sure your database config the production environment is set up correctly?

Comment: Yes, I use the same config in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted tech support and it turned out to be a matter of configuration in the hosting server (Remote Database Access Hosts, which I thought was for MySQL only).

Comment: This helped me. And here's the link on how to do it:
https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/